# Why LinkedList in java both extends AbstractSequentialList and implements List?

Tags: java, linked-list

Why LinkedList in java both extends AbstractSequentialList and implements List in the same time when AbstractSequentialList already implements List interface?

The same for ArrayList (e. AbstractList, i. List).

Is there any technical reason or maybe just for clarity?